# WinForms - Passing values from one Form to another

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a GUI over WinForms with some buttons and textboxes in it. There's also a Save Button, where the entries from the Textboxes get written into a csv. That works so far. Now I wanted to create a second Form and move some Textboxes from Form1 into that. That worked too, but I want to read the Textboxes from Form1 in Form2 and that doesn't work. Here the code example:

```
 public void SettingsSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Proc.setParams(LocationBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(nFCBox.Text, usC),SourceFile.Text,Filename.Text,FilesLocation.Text
        Proc.saveCurrentSettings();
    }
```

He can't find "LocationBox.Text" because this is from "Form1". When I try to create a new instance of the object in the button method with "Form1 form1 = new Form1();" he tells me he can't access it because of the security plane/tier. I tried to set everything to public but that still doesn't work

Comment: Try creating a public method in the new form that will return the value of the LocationBox - something like:
`public string GetLocation(){
  return LocationBox.Text;
}`
Then you should be able to do something like `form1.GetLocation()`

Comment: Still doesn't work. He can't find "LocationBox.Text". I tried to create a new instance of Form1 before the method and in the method but still the same problem.

Comment: uzi42tmp, NDraskovic, means to create that method inside the `form1` class, however you'd still need to pass a reference to form1 to your second form - `new` creates a `new` instance. There are plenty of answers around that explain how to pass a value between forms, quite a few of them are on the right of this question in the related section

Comment: This seems to be one of the most popular questions on SO ;-]

Comment: Awesome! That helped! Thank you a lot! I was looking for that answer a couple of hours!

Comment: Oh wait. It works now but my Form2 is messed up now. I have every single element (buttons,textboxes etc) from Form1 in it and can't delete them because the fields in the control box are gey. What to do?I open Form2 from Form1 over a stripMenu: public void showInputToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
            form2.Show();
        }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your parameters from Form1 to Form2 through the constructor so your Form2 constructor and save them to fields inside Form2 should be like the following

```
String LocationBoxValue;
public Form2(String locationBoxValue,int fCBoxValue, String sourceFileValue, String filenameValue,String filesLocationValue)
{
this.LocationBoxValue = locationBoxValue; //and do the same for the remaining parameters
}
```

Now inside form1 when you try to show the form2 your code should look something like the following

```
Form2 dlg=new Form2(LocationBox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(nFCBox.Text, usC),SourceFile.Text,Filename.Text,FilesLocation.Text);
dlg.Show(); //Or ShowDialog()
```

Finally you can access the parameters directly through the saved fields

Comment: You could... but there are better ways, You'd be stuck with an old location box value on the second form here if it were to change

Comment: I agree with you however this wasn't required in the question. It can be easily achieved by applying the same concept however instead of passing the values he can pass a reference to the original form but this depends on his situation. but it has some other pitfalls like what if form2 read the value from form1 and took action based on the value then value changed on form2 ?? there are some business considerations here